# How to write sql request through Active Record Query Interface with joins two tables where condition - array of ids

Tags: mysql, ruby, activerecord

This is pure ActiveRecord without Rails models, just connection to another mysql db.
I tried to write a request like this:

`Product.joins('inner join oc_product_description on oc_product_description.product_id = oc_product.product_id').where('product_id = ?',[64,66,70,71])`

and got error `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: Column 'product_id' in where clause is ambiguous)`

when I add unique table name like this `.where('oc_product.product_id = ?',[64,66,70,71])`

I got another error `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: Operand should contain 1 column(s))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `IN` for multiple values (Array):

```
Product.joins('inner join oc_product_description on oc_product_description.product_id = oc_product.product_id')
       .where('oc_product.product_id IN (?)',[64,66,70,71])
```

Answer (score 0):

= is used for looking a single value. If you want to use an array, the sql syntax is

`.where('oc_product.product_id IN ?',[64,66,70,71])`

Not sure how ActiveRecord works but you can try this.